# setting iPhone to Slovenian language

Tags: iphone, localization

I have created the Slovenian *strings file and its shown as "Slovenian - Slovenia" in XCode.

But I can't find any way on the iPhone language settings to set to Slovenian language?

Is there no Slovenian language on the iPhone or is there any other way to set the language to Slovenian?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the currently available languages on iPhone (from the technical spec of iPhone 4S):

English (U.S.), English (UK), Chinese (Simplified), Chinese (Traditional), French, German, Italian, Japanese, Korean, Spanish, Arabic, Catalan, Croatian, Czech, Danish, Dutch, Finnish, Greek, Hebrew, Hungarian, Indonesian, Malay, Norwegian, Polish, Portuguese, Portuguese (Brazil), Romanian, Russian, Slovak, Swedish, Thai, Turkish, Ukrainian, Vietnamese

So unfortunately there's no Slovenian language. Maybe later Apple will support that, but currently there's no point in adding a localization option for it in your app.

Comment: thanks for the list - but this is not complete, eg Netherlands is missing from the list but is supported on iPhone